# Alacritty delete line with Cmd + Backspace

Tags: macos, shell, yaml, alacritty

Recently switched from Iterm to Alacritty for various reasons. One thing that I'm now realizing I used a lot is command + backspace to delete and entire line (Yes I'm aware of CTR + U, but that's not muscle memory for me). Is there a way to set up a shortcut for line clear in alacrity?

Comment: Does adding the line `  - { key: Back,     mods: Command, chars: "\x15"                       }` to your alacritty.yml file achieve your desired outcome? (per https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/474#issuecomment-338803299)

Comment: it does! you wanna post as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: Sure thing; glad it solved your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the line  `- { key: Back, mods: Command, chars: "\x15" }` to the alacritty.yml file will delete the entire line with "Cmd+Backspace" on macOS.

Also, here are some additional keybinding changes I've made to my alacritty setup that may make your life easier (per https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/474#issuecomment-338803299):

```
  - { key: Left,     mods: Alt,     chars: "\x1bb"                       } # Skip word left
  - { key: Right,    mods: Alt,     chars: "\x1bf"                       } # Skip word right
  - { key: Left,     mods: Command, chars: "\x1bOH",   mode: AppCursor   } # Home
  - { key: Right,    mods: Command, chars: "\x1bOF",   mode: AppCursor   } # End
  - { key: Back,     mods: Command, chars: "\x15"                        } # Delete line
  - { key: Back,     mods: Alt,     chars: "\x1b\x7f"                    } # Delete word
```

Comment: Since Alacritty Version 0.13.0 _(last week)_, YAML-config got deprecated. _(replaced by TOML)_

Answer (score 1):

With the new TOML config file format, you can use the following instead:

```ini
[[keyboard.bindings]]
key = "Back"
mods = "Command"
chars = "\u0015"
```